# how to check if a response is in xml format instead of HTML?

Tags: java, android, xml, http

Im working with a server which always sends me XML responds. But sometimes when server is lack or something it reports me about it by sending me back a HTML page (it just a html page informing about the error) but i didn't expect that and my XML parser crashed.
Im using DefaultHttpClient() and I do send header like  `mHttpRequest.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");`
So what is the proper way to ensure i got XML (or other specific format) response?

Comment: Are you correctly checking the status code of the response? If it's an error that leads to the HTML page, you should not get a 200 OK.

Comment: currently i don't and i guess u r right. i'll try to work around returned code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kristian suggested, see if it provides a different Content-Type when HTML is emitted. Failing that I would check for a `<?xml...` line, as apposed to a doctype or whatever is on the HTML page.

Comment: i was actually think that way too

Comment: Not every xml document will start with <?xml

Answer (score 3):

Can you check the content type header on the response?

Something like (if I understand the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) correctly):

```
"text/xml".equals(httpResponse.getEntity().getContentType().getValue());
```

Comment: (In general) It *might* not just be "text/xml" though -- atom feeds are very glaring (and common) counter-example. It might be better to either look for mimes matching "/xml" *and/or* "+xml". See [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

Answer (score 2):

Every XML contains document descriptor `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in the beginning. You can check for this before parsing it.

However, I think you need some error handling and result validation in your parser. Network is not a safe environment - you can easily get a half-broken, malformed, or even forged XML from the network. Good parser should detect that and report corresponding errors, not just crash.

Comment: It might not be UTF-8... But yes, the XML declaration is required for a valid XML document. (Then again, the world isn't perfect :-)

Comment: i got it. it just reports me a caught exception. it not crashes the whole entire app.

Comment: According to [x3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), It is an XML prolog and is optional.